# Why is the 'ordinals' option unavailable in Photoshop's Character palette?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, opentype

[image]

It won't let me click this option and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I read that some options have to do with certain font support, but none of my default OS fonts allow this option either.

Answer (score 1):

These icons all are OpenType features; a specific .otf file may or may not support any or all of them. In this case, your version of Lobster (*shudder*) doesn't support the ordinals feature.

Comment: Nor anything else – although OP is *not* wondering about the other grayed-out icons – than a handful of alternate characters and a couple of dozen ligatures.

Answer (score 1):

Lobster 1.3 does not have the glyphs for ordinals. The 2.001 version [available from Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lobster) includes the glyphs and the OpenType feature.

BTW, the fact that it is a .ttf file doesn't preclude it form having OpenType features. It only indicates that it has TrueType outlines.